# Can I reduce or minimize the size of a picture in Excel 2007?

Tags: image, excel, vba

Can we minimize a picture/image inserted in Excel, so that we are able to see it only when we click on any button (the way we ungroup or group data in Excel)?

Comment: I think this should probably go to SuperUser.

Comment: I know how to compress or reduce the size of picture or image but i wanted to know if it can be minimized too..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Right click on the picture and click on Assign macro (you can do it on a button as well)

Click on New to create a new macro.

You will get the following code in the VB editor:

```
Sub Picture1_Click()

End Sub
```

Add those 3 lines in between to resize to 50%:

```
Sub Picture1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

FYI the name of the selected picture is showing before the formula bar.

If you get that, you will be able to do the other way around by searching a bit on how excel macro and vba works.